# What is a most benefit way to gather server hardware utilization, app logs, app jvm metrics, using Elastic-Stack?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, metricbeat, elastic-beats

Besides ELK standard goal for gathering application logs data i want to leverage this stack for advanced data collection such as JVM metrics (via JMX) and host's cpu/ram/disk/network utilization.

The most suitable one i thought is using `metricbeat`, but i doubt if `metricbeat` is enough for purposes described above.

Since i aiming at minimal stack of things to configure, will `Metricbeat`-`Elasticsearch`-`Kibana` be enough for collecting `app logs`,`app jvm metrics`,`host's hardware utilization` or there are some more suitable alternatives ?

***UPDATE***

Oh, i see now, that i need also `filebeat` besides `metricbeat` for gathering `app logs`.
Is there any out of the box single solution that combines `filebeat` and `metricbeat` agents ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Filebeat and Metricbeat are separate binaries and you need to run both:

- Filebeat to collect your logs (and potentially parse them with Elasticsearch Ingest node).
- Metricbeat with the system module for cpu/ram/disk/network and we also have a JMX / Jolokia module for that functionality.